# How to insert data use table adapter in visual basic without class?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, datagridview

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Me.KELASTableAdapter.InsertQuery(TextBox5.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox8.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

this my step, but can't add.. please help

Answer (score 0):

It is bad form to have a Try...Catch without handing the catch.  I recommend you either remove the Try...Catch block or add some code to either log or display an error.  I typically capture the exception.message and the exception.stacktrace, for the exception as well as any exception.innerexception objects.